# Knockout.js - custom "template" binding that can be used in the same data-binding as "with"

Tags: knockout.js

I am heavily invested in the knockout.js ecosystem.

I'm not sure why it's not more popular, but it does everything I want with minimal bloat.

Now I am also an extreme syntax minimalist.

I think reading a lot of braces, commas, quotes, etc can be really tiring to read, giving a fatigue while reading code.

The default for rendering a template **and** setting the child at the same time is:

`<div data-bind="template: { name: 'TemplateName', data: child }"></div>`

What I would like to enable is this syntax though:

`<div data-bind="template: 'TemplateName', with: child"></div>`

By default this creates this Exception though:

> You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.

After a lot of hacking around this version that I have that seems to work:

```
let original_template_binding   = ko.bindingHandlers.template;
let original_with_binding       = ko.bindingHandlers.with;

ko.bindingHandlers.template = 
{
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) 
    {
        var with_value = allBindings.get('with');

        if ( with_value !== undefined )
            bindingContext = bindingContext.createChildContext(() => with_value);

        return original_template_binding.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) 
    {
        var with_value = allBindings.get('with');

        if ( with_value !== undefined )
            bindingContext = bindingContext.createChildContext(() => with_value);

        return original_template_binding.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);
   }
};

ko.bindingHandlers['with'] = 
{
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) 
    {
        if ( allBindings.has('template') )
            return undefined;

        return original_with_binding.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

So in short:

- if the `template` binding detects a `with` value it passes it as a child context
- if the `with` binding detects a `template` binding it disables itself

Questions:

- It *seems* to work, but is there any simpler/maybe less risky way to add similar functionality.
- Any significant performance dangers this could impact. Is the allBindings accessor cheap?

Answer (score 1):

You can think of an alternative where you actually use full-blown components when encapsulating "a domain of operations" and create binding hanlder only to address custom mini-elements like inputs etc.

If you where to go through the route of components, you would start by registering their templates like normal:

```
ko.components.register('modules-mainApp', {
                viewModel: { require: 'js/modules/app/app' },
                template: { require: 'text!js/modules/app/app.html' }
            });
```

On the example above, because r.js is used, the definition is async, but you can very well just have the viewModel be a factory function, not a static object on the declaration.

This will allow for dynamic bindings, very clean syntax, and the ability to always keep state up-to-date in multiple components using 1 root reference for performance reasons.

The end result can now be bound to an observable that will define the behaviour  of each component in a centralized memory array:

```
self.loadedModules.push(new appModule({
                    name: modName,
                    state: self.loadModuleState(modName),
                    config: self.loadModuleConfig(modName),
                    active: false
                }));
```

And now the above could be bound to lets say an element like so:

```
<main role="main" class="pb-3" data-bind="component: { name: activeModule().templateName, params: activeModule().params }">
            </main>
```

By alternating the 'activeModule' observable, you feed both the template name and the new data to be fed - which depending on how you handle your references will only re-rendered once - if the activeModule is -rebound to a different object. You could even just leave component: activeModule, but i wanted to have explicit the bindings, since i want the engine to only rethink about updates if the "data" part changes, as the template name would be bound to the component anyway - and static.

Not sure if this would be close to what you want exactly, but just wanted to give a different way to handle cleanness in binding and syntaxminimalism